# Let apache mod_rewrite hide subdirectories

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a directory `/var/www/html/` which contains an `index.php` and a subdirectory `sites`. Below `sites` I have directories called `jason`, `john`, `marge` and so on...
The webserver is rechable under `https://family.local`

What I would like to do is the following:

1. When `https://family.local` is called apache should return `index.php` - this was easy
2. When `https://family.local/jason` is called apache should look into `sites/jason` for `index.php` - no way found - always return 404 or internal server error
3. When `https://family.local/jason/2022` is called apache should look into `sites/jason/` if there is a subdirectory `2022` and deliver index.php
4. If any path is called which not exists - return the `index.php` from root directory with `?error=404&page=nameofrequestedpage` - this was also easy except that it is delivered with 200 instead of 404

Thank you so much for any help

Comment: In what context are you writing these directives... `.htaccess`, `<Directory>`, _virtualhost_ or _server_? What did you use for #1 and #4 (which you say were "easy")? These rules need to work _together_, the order is important. For #2 and #3 you are not including the trailing slash - is that correct?